# Use 16x2 LCD Display with ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, lcd, fasm

I've been trying to use a 16x2 LCD Display with my FASMARM Program. The exact model of the LCD Display is `tc1602a-21t`. I am also using a raspberry Pi 3 for this project.

So, to make life easier I wrote a few functions, `turn_gpio_on`  and `turn_gpio_off` which turn the Pin number located in r0 to `HIGH` or `LOW` respectively. Also have a `sleep` function which makes the program sleep for `r0` milliseconds. Lastly I have another function called `set_gpio_to_output`and `set_gpio_to_input` which in turn set the pin in `r0` to either output input mode.
I just listed these functions because They are rather frequent in my code.

My code for the project is located [here](https://pastebin.com/zShCemu1).

First I declare the pin numbers for the R/S, Enable, and the last 4 Data pins. I made sure to wire everything up correctly and tested it thoroughly so i can say for sure there is no problem with the wiring.

From the `start` method i then call the `init_display` function which should set up the display. However, nothing ever happens to the lcd display. It just turns the first row on, because of the power pins but it seems like the data pins never do anything.

I mainly followed [this](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD/blob/master/Adafruit_CharLCD/Adafruit_CharLCD.py) Python script which does the same thing i want to do, but in python.

It says there to initialize write the number 0x33 as a command and then the 0x32. I do both of them on line 30 and 34 respectively. The `mov r1, #0` command before these lines, indicate that the passed integer should be sent to the display as a command.

I tested everything with LEDs so many times, with a slower delay, and they always showed up correctly. For every time I call `write8` the LEDs turn on first the Higher 4 bits and then the lower 4 bits. So theoretically the display should be initialized correctly and show a blinking light. But nothing happens, it just stays with a blue backlight and the first row highlighted. Just as if you set it up without any pins except for the power ones.

Is there anything I wrote wrong? And if so what? I am extremely confused now.

Comment: Do you have the R/W pin of the LCD module tied low?

Comment: yes i have not connected it to any cables

Comment: If the pin isn't connected to anything, then the answer to my question is "no".  The module isn't going to work reliably with one of its inputs floating.

Comment: I think i misunderstood something, if a pin is not connected to anything, isnt that pin always low?

Comment: I'm still confused as to why, but as soon as I grounded the R/W pin, it started to work. So if you could explain why I would accept it as the correct answer c:

Comment: A floating pin has no reason to be in any particular state, unless the designer of the chip incorporated a pull-up or pull-down resistor to ensure one.  I believe the HD44780 chip used in text LCDs has pull-*ups* on all input pins, so the module was permanently in 'read' mode.  (You were risking damage to the module by applying signals to the D4-D7 pins while they were in output mode.)

Comment: Well luckily nothing got damaged, but it is working now, thank you so much for your answer